# Filtering array of objects with multiple attribute on multiple condition

Tags: javascript

I am trying to filter an array of objects with multiple attribute on multiple condition. so I'm creating an param array which consists of of multiple array holding the parameters. For example

```
var params = [
    ["id", "equals", "11060"],
    ["user_id", "exact", "84"]
];
```

first element is key , second one is condition  and third one is value.
so first filtering condition is
`id == '11060'` and second one is `user_id = '84'`

```
// data to filter
    var originalData = [{
        "id": 11141,
        "user_id": 84,
        "received": "26 Jan 2017",
        "approvalstatus": "Approved"
    }, {
        "id": 11080,
        "user_id": 84,
        "received": "25 Jan 2017",
        "approvalstatus": "Approved"
    }, {
        "id": 11079,
        "user_id": 84,
        "received": "25 Jan 2017",
        "approvalstatus": "Approved"
    }, {
        "id": 11078,
        "user_id": 84,
        "received": "25 Jan 2017",
        "approvalstatus": "Approved"
    }, {
        "id": 11060,
        "user_id": 84,
        "received": "24 Jan 2017",
        "approvalstatus": "Approved"
    }];
```

Following is my filtering function.

```
   filteredData = originalData.filter(function(item) {
        params.forEach(function(value, index) {
            var cond = value[1];
            var cKey = value[0];
            var cValue = value[2];
            var flag = false;
            if (cond == 'equals') {
                if (item[cKey] == Number(cValue)) {
                    flag = true;
                }
            } else if (cond == 'exact'){
                if (item[cKey].toString() == cValue) {
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
            return flag;
        });
        return false;
    });
```

but it's not working. What I am doing wrong? TIA.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r89mkaf8/1/)

Comment: you could add some data to filter.

Comment: added them in fiddle, can add here gladly. but size of post increases and somewhere read about SO users tendency to avoid large post.

Comment: your equal or exact makes no sense, you could use strict or nonstrict, or just the sign of the comarison.

Comment: I think it's because he use strings even for numbers

Comment: But that part of code is not making any issue. equals I used for numeric check and exact used for string compare.

Comment: This does not work because forEach is not synchronous. `return false` will always trigger first. Use a for...each loop instead.

Comment: @JohnSmith You're sort of right. It is synchronous, but the return flag isn't going to do anything...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do a forEach(), the return value will not be transmitted as the return value of the filtering function.
Also, you didn't decided if the value must pass all test successfully or only one. I assume it's all test must be passed successfully.
If it's only one of them, the code is slightly different.

```
filteredData = originalData.filter(function(item) {
    var i, ntest, cKey, cValue, flag;
    for(i=0, ntest=params.length; i<ntest; ++i) {
        cKey = params[i][0];
        cValue = params[i][2];
        switch(params[i][1]) {
            case "equals":
                if(item[cKey] != Number(cValue)) return false;
            break;
            case "exact":
                if(item[cKey].toString() != cValue) return false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

### Problem:

You cannot return from `forEach`. `forEach` will return an array to `filter` and an array is *truthy*. So, the resulting data will contain all the elements.

### Solution:

`for` can be used instead of `forEach`. To check if all the conditions in the array are satisfied, check if `flag` is set to `false` and return from there to exclude that element from resulting array.

```js
var originalData = [{
    "id": 11141,
    "user_id": 84,
    "received": "26 Jan 2017",
    "approvalstatus": "Approved"
}, {
    "id": 11080,
    "user_id": 84,
    "received": "25 Jan 2017",
    "approvalstatus": "Approved"
}, {
    "id": 11079,
    "user_id": 84,
    "received": "25 Jan 2017",
    "approvalstatus": "Approved"
}, {
    "id": 11078,
    "user_id": 84,
    "received": "25 Jan 2017",
    "approvalstatus": "Approved"
}, {
    "id": 11060,
    "user_id": 84,
    "received": "24 Jan 2017",
    "approvalstatus": "Approved"
}];


var params = [
    ["id", "equals", "11060"],
    ["user_id", "exact", "84"]
];


filteredData = originalData.filter(function(item) {
    var flag = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
        var value = params[i];
        var condition = value[1];

        if (condition === 'equals') {
            flag = item[value[0]] === Number(value[2]);
        } else if (condition === 'exact') {
            flag = item[value[0]].toString() === value[2];
        }

        // If flag is false, return from here
        // No need to check other conditions
        if (flag === false) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return flag;
});

console.log(filteredData);
```

---

### Better(?) Alternative

I'll recommend to use an object instead of array of arrays to store the filter criteria.

```js
var originalData = [{
    "id": 11141,
    "user_id": 84,
    "received": "26 Jan 2017",
    "approvalstatus": "Approved"
}, {
    "id": 11080,
    "user_id": 84,
    "received": "25 Jan 2017",
    "approvalstatus": "Approved"
}, {
    "id": 11079,
    "user_id": 84,
    "received": "25 Jan 2017",
    "approvalstatus": "Approved"
}, {
    "id": 11078,
    "user_id": 84,
    "received": "25 Jan 2017",
    "approvalstatus": "Approved"
}, {
    "id": 11060,
    "user_id": 84,
    "received": "24 Jan 2017",
    "approvalstatus": "Approved"
}];


// Filter criteria
var params = {
    id: 11060,
    user_id: 84
};

// Get keys from params
var keys = Object.keys(params);

filteredData = originalData.filter(function(item) {
    var flag = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        var key = keys[i];

        // Check if value from filter criterial and
        // current element are equal
        flag = item[key] === params[key];
        if (flag === false) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return flag;
});

console.log(filteredData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and check every condition.

```js
var params = [["id", "equals", "11060"], ["user_id", "exact", "84"]],
    originalData = [{ id: 11141, user_id: 84, received: "26 Jan 2017", approvalstatus: "Approved" }, { id: 11080, user_id: 84, received: "25 Jan 2017", approvalstatus: "Approved" }, { id: 11079, user_id: 84, received: "25 Jan 2017", approvalstatus: "Approved" }, { id: 11078, user_id: 84, received: "25 Jan 2017", approvalstatus: "Approved" }, { id: 11060, user_id: 84, received: "24 Jan 2017", approvalstatus: "Approved" }],
    filteredData = originalData.filter(function (item) {
        return params.every(function (value) {
            var cond = value[1],
                cKey = value[0],
                cValue = value[2];
            if (cond == 'equals') {
                return item[cKey] == Number(cValue);
            } else if (cond == 'exact') {
                return item[cKey].toString() == cValue;
            }
            return false;
        });
    });

console.log(filteredData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A short version, would be, to convert all conditions to functions and call it with `item`.

```js
var params = [["id", "equals", "11060"], ["user_id", "exact", "84"]],        
    conditions = params.map(function (a) {
        switch (a[1]) {
            case 'equals': return function (o) { return o[a[0]] == Number(a[2]); };
            case 'exact': return function (o) { return o[a[0]].toString() == a[2]; };
        }
    }),
    originalData = [{ id: 11141, user_id: 84, received: "26 Jan 2017", approvalstatus: "Approved" }, { id: 11080, user_id: 84, received: "25 Jan 2017", approvalstatus: "Approved" }, { id: 11079, user_id: 84, received: "25 Jan 2017", approvalstatus: "Approved" }, { id: 11078, user_id: 84, received: "25 Jan 2017", approvalstatus: "Approved" }, { id: 11060, user_id: 84, received: "24 Jan 2017", approvalstatus: "Approved" }],
    filteredData = originalData.filter(function (item) {
        return conditions.every(function (condition) {
            return condition(item);
        });
    });

console.log(filteredData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var filteredData = originalData.filter(function(data){ 
  var found = false;
  params.map(function(param){ 
    switch(param[1]){ 
        case "equals":
          if(data[param[0]] == param[2]){ found = true; }
        break;
        case "exact":
          if(data[param[0]] == param[2]){ found = true; }
        break;
    }
  })
  return found;
})

console.log(filteredData);
```